# 301 redirect to turn off pagination

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We had enabled pagination on our search results page where the results were split up in multiple pages. For various reasons, we have since moved away from this.

**I am looking for the following 301 redirect**

REDIRECT FROM

```
1) www.example.com/index.php?query1=ABC&query2=XYZ&page=
2) www.example.com/index.php?query1=ABC&query2=XYZ&page=0&query3=PQR
3) www.example.com/index.php?query1=ABC&query2=XYZ&query3=PQR&page=1
...
```

Essentially the redirect should cover all values for query parameter 'page'

REDIRECT TO

```
www.example.com/?query1=ABC&query2=XYZ&query3=PQR
```

I'm not good with .htaccess redirects and would appreciate the help.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: @MarcB - I thought I mentioned in my original question that I was looking for a 301 Redirect. I have edited it to specify this in bold

Comment: "I need" is not a question. It's a demand for someone else to do your job for you. Show what you've attempted, and we'll maybe help try fix that.

Comment: @MarcB - Point well taken. Sorry about that. I have updated the language in my question. I didnt mean to "demand" but agree that it was a poor choice of words.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:(.*?)&)?page=[^&]*(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ ?%1&%2 [NC,NE,L,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. The site is live and I will test your suggestion later tonight. I will accept this answer once I confirm that it works.

Comment: Just a note that `/index.php?query1=ABC&query2=XYZ&page=` will be redirected to `/index.php?query1=ABC&query2=XYZ` since original URL doesn't have `query3` parameter.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. I want the behavior to be exactly as you stated. However the Rewrite code didn't quite work - i.e. the redirection didn't happen at all. I have other RewriteRule statements in my .htaccess. Could that be the reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes other rules can conflict. Just place this rule as very first rule.

Comment: Ok. I will try that again tonight and report back. Thanks again!